# how we remove nodemodules error of highcharts in angular 10 project?

Tags: highcharts, angular10

When I start my app it displays an error . All the working of highcharts are worked means 2d as well as 3-d. I able to design 2d as well as 3d-charts, but problem is that this error prints in console.

`GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/highcharts-3d/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

In app.module.ts:
`import { HighchartsChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';`

In component: `import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';`

In package.json: `"highcharts": "^8.1.2", "highcharts-3d": "^0.1.7", "highcharts-angular": "^2.7.0",`

In package-lock.json: `"highcharts": { "version": "8.1.2", "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/highcharts/-/highcharts-8.1.2.tgz", "integrity": "sha512-Q124Lj+2+bVY2MKMd7d8uSVAmhZVzWgknUUzUBEC27S94dCyK6PBgahuwiMP/ET4w7qSFBBi4OC77ZUb0Vnuyg==" }, "highcharts-3d": { "version": "0.1.7", "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/highcharts-3d/-/highcharts-3d-0.1.7.tgz", "integrity": "sha1-tRqPhw2Qe0BjWuOetz1F7bkKkfs=" }, "highcharts-angular": { "version": "2.7.0", "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/highcharts-angular/-/highcharts-angular-2.7.0.tgz", "integrity": "sha512-UXH7b+3QfGrsaKGdQ+QvgTVc3sP1LUjKtQWS8CcnKagySLUC/62RiZ3s2IPNwpqkJAedop+6GbV19MNyUUPfFA==", "requires": { "tslib": "^1.10.0" },`

Any suggestion will help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Narun Dutta, It looks that the import of the `highcharts-3d` module is wrong, you should use: `import Highcharts3d from 'highcharts/highcharts-3d'`.

Comment: in app.module or in component where I use highcharts

Comment: In the both places.